# how to improve insert into a list, use multi core

Tags: c#, list, parallel-processing

I have to read 100.000 rows from database, I use this code :

```
List<elementClass> Listelement = new List<elementClass>();
using (DbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (reader .Read())
    {
        elementClass element= new elementClass();
        DatabaseClass.ReadFromObject(reader , element);
        Listelement.Add(element);
    }
}
```

ReadFromObject  :

```
public static void ReadFromObject(DbDataReader dr, Object obj)
{
    DataTable tableDescriptor = dr.GetSchemaTable();

    try
    {
        //Id - Identifier
        obj.GetType().GetProperty("Id").SetValue(obj, dr.GetValue(dr.GetOrdinal("Id")), null);

        PropertyInfo[] properties = obj.GetType().GetProperties();
        foreach (PropertyInfo pi in properties)
        {
            if (!ExistColumn(tableDescriptor, pi.Name)) continue;   // field not found
            if (dr[pi.Name] == DBNull.Value) continue;

            if (pi.PropertyType.IsEnum) { }
            else
            {
                switch (pi.PropertyType.Name)
                {
                    case "DateTime":
                        object dateValue = null;
                        if (dr[pi.Name].GetType().Name == "String")
                            dateValue = F24Common.Utility.DateFromString(dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal(pi.Name)));
                        else
                            dateValue = dr.GetDateTime(dr.GetOrdinal(pi.Name));
                        pi.SetValue(obj, dateValue, null);
                        break;
                    default:
                         pi.SetValue(obj, dr.GetValue(dr.GetOrdinal(pi.Name)), null);
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

    }
    catch (Exception )
    {

    }
}
```

There is something definitely wrong with this code, it's too slow (the whole processing takes 45-50 minutes). 
Is it possibile to fill the list using more than one CPU core (I have a quad-core CPU available) at the same time ?

Comment: Is the order of entries within the list important? Because if it isn't, the obvious thing to do is to build 4 lists, one in each thread, and concatenate them at the end. This avoids all locking.

Comment: @Damon : I was thinking to use that , but I have a file to generate after this list, and I don't know yet how to know the 4 list are completed to begin the file (I have to read a little) :)

Comment: You want a barrier for that. Once a thread is done, you have it hit the barrier, which will block it until the threshold is reached (i.e. all of them are done). Choose the threshold being 5, and have the main thread block on the barrier too. Workers exit after waking up, the main thread writes the file. I'm not a C# programmer, but it seems C# has one [readily available](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.threading.barrier.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a glance, I would think that the bottleneck lies with the amount of reflection. I'd suggest having a read of Jon Skeets excellent [Making Reflection fly article](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2008/08/09/making-reflection-fly-and-exploring-delegates.aspx). You can then cache the appropriate delegates keyed on the type of `obj`.

I would be hesitant to access the DataReader from multiple threads as I would doubt that it is safe to do so.

Comment: Yes, it totally is - this is about the worst (slowest) way at all to code any reflection. All the MethodInfo instances can be static and cached between method calls to ReadFromObject - if you actually want to stay with this primitive code and not use to a LINQ provider for that, which would REALLY speed things up.

Comment: ok I will read this article
and @TomTom : how to use Linq to change this ReadFromObject  !

Comment: SImple - there will not be any ReadFromObject method to start with.